# Perl DBI program terminates because of failed integrity constraint

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi

I am using Perl DBI to insert lots of rows into an Oracle database. It's a bit like this:

```
     INSERT INTO TABLE(COL1_FK, COL2, COL3)
                VALUES(GET_PK_FROM_TABLE('VALUE'), VAL2, VAL3)
```

One of the insert statements is failing owing to an integrity constraint (which is fine). All I want Perl to do is continue executing the remaining INSERT statements. However, Perl decides to terminate the program. How can I change this so Perl continues to the next INSERT statement even if one of them fails?

Comment: do you have `RaiseError` set in the connect call? If so, that will cause any exec failure to throw an error.

Comment: We would need to see the code that you are using.